# Duplicate roles being added with rolify using after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a default role assignment within an after_create callback in my User model, but duplicative roles are always created in the database.

The applicable parts of my User model are as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include RailsSettings::Extend
  after_create :assign_basic_role

  rolify
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :locations, as: :locatable
  has_many :prospects, as: :prospectable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :deals, :through => :prospects
  belongs_to :agency

private
  def assign_basic_role
    self.add_role :basic, self.agency
  end
end
```

And from the console

```
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'basic' AND "roles"."resource_type" = 'Agency' AND "roles"."resource_id" = 11 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND "roles"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 144]]
   (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 144]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 144]]
   (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users_roles" ("user_id", "role_id") VALUES (144, 12)
   (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users_roles" ("user_id", "role_id") VALUES (144, 12)
```

Comment: I've shared the issue with the rolify authors: https://github.com/EppO/rolify/issues/228

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug for sure. Caused me a lot of annoyance. Here's how I got around it:

In your model, 
instead of

```
after_create :create_a_role
```

do

```
after_commit :create_a_role, on: :create
```

No more duplicates. Yay!